# Posgresql ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression, in this query:

```
SELECT SUM(net_value) AS sales,
(SELECT SUM(net_value) FROM sales_view
WHERE document_ = 'NOTA DE CRÉDITO ELECTRÓNICA'
AND month_ BETWEEN 1 AND 12 
GROUP BY year_, month_
ORDER BY year_) AS return,
month_, year_ FROM sales_view
WHERE month_ BETWEEN 1 AND 12 
AND (document_= 'BOLETA NO AFECTA O EXENTA ELECTRÓNICA' OR 
    document_= 'BOLETA ELECTRÓNICA' OR
    document_ = 'FACTURA ELECTRÓNICA' OR
    document_ = 'FACTURA NO AFECTA O EXENTA ELECTRÓNICA')
GROUP BY year_, month_
ORDER BY year_
```

I need your help, please

Answer (score 2):

remove group by inside subquery

```
SELECT SUM(net_value) AS sales,
(SELECT SUM(net_value) FROM sales_view
WHERE document_ = 'NOTA DE CRÉDITO ELECTRÓNICA'
AND month_ BETWEEN 1 AND 12) AS return,
month_, year_ FROM sales_view
WHERE month_ BETWEEN 1 AND 12 
AND (document_= 'BOLETA NO AFECTA O EXENTA ELECTRÓNICA' OR 
    document_= 'BOLETA ELECTRÓNICA' OR
    document_ = 'FACTURA ELECTRÓNICA' OR
    document_ = 'FACTURA NO AFECTA O EXENTA ELECTRÓNICA')
GROUP BY year_, month_
ORDER BY year_
```

but it seems you can change using case when

```
SELECT SUM(net_value) AS sales,
    SUM(case when document_ = 'NOTA DE CRÉDITO ELECTRÓNICA'
    AND month_ BETWEEN 1 AND 12 then net_value else 0 end
       ) as return,
    month_, year_ FROM sales_view
    WHERE month_ BETWEEN 1 AND 12 
    AND (document_= 'BOLETA NO AFECTA O EXENTA ELECTRÓNICA' OR 
        document_= 'BOLETA ELECTRÓNICA' OR
        document_ = 'FACTURA ELECTRÓNICA' OR
        document_ = 'FACTURA NO AFECTA O EXENTA ELECTRÓNICA')
    GROUP BY year_, month_
    ORDER BY year_
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN document_ IN ('BOLETA NO AFECTA O EXENTA ELECTRÓNICA', 'BOLETA ELECTRÓNICA', 'FACTURA ELECTRÓNICA', 'FACTURA NO AFECTA O EXENTA ELECTRÓNICA'net_value
                THEN new_value
           END) AS sales,
       SUM(CASE WHEN document_ in 'NOTA DE CRÉDITO ELECTRÓNICA'
                THEN net_value
           END) AS return
       month_, year_
FROM sales_view
WHERE month_ BETWEEN 1 AND 12 
GROUP BY year_, month_
ORDER BY year_, month_;
```

If you are really querying from a view (that is at all complicated), you should find that this is much more efficient that your approach.  The view is only referenced once.